# How should I change my tkinter code to rearrange the elements on my page?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm learning tkinter and getting stumped in one area.  Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

def button_press():
    showinfo('info','pressed button')    

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x500')

f = Frame(root)
f.pack()
Label(f, text="this is a line of text").pack(side=LEFT)
s = StringVar(value='enter here')
Entry(f, textvariable=s, width=100).pack(side=LEFT)
Button(f, text='Button', command=button_press).pack(side=RIGHT)

root.mainloop()
```

It produces:

[image]

But I want to align the text vertically with the entry field like this:

[image]

What do I need to change to make that happen?

Comment: Do you want all of that blank space to the left of the entry and label? If the label is very, very long, do you want it to be over the button or stop at the edge of the entry?

Answer (score 3):

Using `.pack()` is not advisable if you want to create more complex Frame structures.
Instead assign the items to variables and place those into a `.grid()`.

`.grid` splits up your frame into different rows and columns or "sticks" them on a certain place.
below an example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo


def button_press():
    showinfo('info', 'pressed button')


root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x500')

f = Frame(root)
f.pack()
l1 = Label(f, text="this is a line of text")
l1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
s = StringVar(value='enter here')
entry = Entry(f, textvariable=s, width=100)
entry.grid(row=2, column=1)
button = Button(f, text='Button', command=button_press)
button.grid(row=2, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I just want to say that your answer is right on the money. That said, if I may play devil's advocate, this *can* be achieved with `pack()` (albeit perhaps not as intuitively as with `grid()`). You could leverage `pack`'s `before` and/or `after` arguments for greater control of packing order, or you could do some fancy footwork with containing `Frame`s...or you could do the sane thing and just use `grid()` ;)

Comment: Grid did the trick.  before/after look incomprehensible at the moment.  Addring extra frames could work but it would make the code harder to read I think